# Anonymous function losing scope

Tags: javascript, scope, anonymous-function

Why is this not working?

```
var img = new Image();
this.dimensions = [ ];
var m = this;
img.onload = function(){ 
    return function(){
        m.dimensions = [ this.width, this.height ]; 
    }
};
img.src = 'images/whatever.jpg';


console.log(this.dimensions);
[]
```

(inside of a JS object, hence the "this")

EDIT: working code

```
var img = new Image();
this.dimensions = [  ];
var m = this;
img.onload = function(){ 
    m.dimensions.push(this.width, this.height);  
    console.log(m.dimensions) // had to wait
};
img.src = 'whatever.jpg';
```

Comment: The dimensions array is not being set to the width and height of the image

Comment: Inside of the function, console.log([ this.width, this.height ]) returns them fine. I am creating the `m` variable to keep the scope of this correct.

Comment: You likely want to ensure you function is being called: that last comment cannot be true. One or the other is false.

Comment: I fixed it. return function() is needless and for some reason, `m.dimensions.push( this.width, this.height )` works while `m.dimensions = [ this.width, this.height ]` still doesn't.

Comment: Your code does not agree with my logic :( Please consider a jsfiddle.

Comment: `this` can be difficult to grasp in JavaScript. But you're in luck; Quirksmode has an excellent article on the topic: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html

Comment: Skyd was right. I forgot Javascript doesn't wait to keep running. http://jsfiddle.net/7snLg/
Thank you for the help everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure console.log(this.dimensions) is being run AFTER the image has loaded? What you've added to img.onload is a callback function to run after the image has finished loading in DOM. Until that img has finished loading, m.dimensions will not be set yet. The image does not load immediately when you add the callback, but loads asynchronously and can finish whenever.

In other words, you are running console.log(this.dimensions) before the dimensions has been set yet (before the onload callback is run). I bet if you wrapped the console.log inside a setTimeout call with say 5 seconds, then it would log what you expected.

Comment: You're right. I've made this stupid mistake before, I wish Javascript would execute line-after-line.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `this` changes meaning inside new function definitions. You solve this by caching this in a local variable. Here, that's already done; your saving it in the variable `m`. So just use `m` instead of `this`.

```
var img = new Image();
this.dimensions = [ ];
var m = this;
img.onload = function(){ 
    return function(){
        m.dimensions = [ m.width, m.height ]; 
    }
};
img.src = 'images/whatever.jpg';
```

Here's a good tutorial explaining how `this` changes meaning in different contexts: http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/30/understanding-javascripts-this/

Comment: This still will have issues. `m.dimensions = ...` is *never executed*.

Answer (score 1):

Consider that this code *won't* alert:

```
img.onload = function(){ 
    return function(){
        alert("hi")
    }
};
```

Then consider the standard (likely desired) "double-closure":

```
img.onload = (function(m){ 
    return function(){
        alert(m)
    }
})(this)
```

Happy coding.

Comment: Is this what one would call a self-invocation function in JS?

Comment: @RussellDias It's not self-invoking as it's invoked manually :) I think, perhaps "an anonymous function that is executed immediately".